# How can i properly call the winningHand method into displayRoundResult?

Tags: java

I made the adjustments so now my winningHand method works properly, Can someone please explain why is it that everytime I try to call the winningHand method into displayroundresult, it doesn't work? I

```
private final char _YES = 'Y';
private final int _HIGH_BESTOF = 5;
private int winningHand;
// ***********************************************************************

// central method that holds the majority of the game's logic
public void playGame()
{
    int numberOfRounds;
    int p1Score = 0;
    int p2Score = 0;
    int round = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors..");
    while (true)
    {
        numberOfRounds = playToWins(scan);

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRounds; i++)
    {
        char p1 = chooseHandShape();
        char p2 = chooseHandShape();
        System.out.println("P1: " + p1 + " P2: " + p2);
        //wwinningHand always returns the number 2?
        winningHand = winningHand(p1,p2);


        displayRoundResult(p1Score, p2Score);   
    }//end of for statement

    //displayMatchResult here
    //displayMatchResult(round, p1Score, p2Score);
    //System.out.println( + round);
    //... ask how rounds come in to play?

    //if p1Score = p2Score , play another round to break the tie
    } //end of while true statement


    // winningHand(player1, player2);


}

// display round results
private void displayRoundResult(int p1Score, int p2Score)
{
    // how do i call winningHandMethod here?
    int winningHand;
    winningHand = getwinningHand();

    if (winningHand == 1)
    {
        p1Score =  + 1;
    }
    if (winningHand == 2)
    {
        p2Score =  + 1;
    }

}

// display match results
private void displayMatchResult(int round, int p1Score, int p2Score)
{
    System.out.println("Player 1 has " + p1Score + " points & Player 2 has " + p2Score + " points");
    if (p1Score > p2Score)
    {           System.out.println("Player 1 has won!");
    }
    if (p2Score > p1Score)
    {
        System.out.println("Player 2 has won!");
    }
    else if (p1Score == p2Score)
    {
        System.out.println("Its a tie! You must play another round");
    }


}//end of displayMatchResult

// get what will be the round goal score
private int playToWins(Scanner scan)
{
    int numberOfRounds;

    System.out.println("Play round to? (Max is 5)");
    numberOfRounds = scan.nextInt();

    while (numberOfRounds > _HIGH_BESTOF)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value between 1 and 5, your last input was incorrect!");
        numberOfRounds = scan.nextInt();
    }

    return numberOfRounds;
}

// given two hands choose which one wins
// possible values for either parameter are 'R','P' or 'S'
// use the RPS rules to determine the winner
// return 0 for tie, 1 for player 1 win or 2 for player 2 win
private int winningHand(char player1, char player2)
{
    int winningHand = 0;

    // is this the right way to set it up? If i didnt add this, it'd keep telling me
    // that R,P, & S havent been intialized
    char Rock = 'R';
    char Paper = 'P';
    char Scissors = 'S';

    // tie
    if (player1 == (player2))
    {
        winningHand = 0;
    }

    // if player 1 wins
    if (player1 == Rock && player2 == Scissors)
    {
        winningHand = 1;
    }
    if (player1 == Scissors && player2 == Paper)
    {
        winningHand = 1;
    }
    if (player1 == Paper && player2 == Rock)
    {
        winningHand = 1;
    }

    // if player 2 wins
    if (player1 == Scissors && player2 == Rock)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }
    if (player1 == Paper && player2 == Scissors)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }
    if (player1 == Rock && player2 == Paper)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }

    return winningHand;
}

int getWinningHand()
{
    return winningHand;
}

// method that randomly chooses a hand shape
// returns 'R' for rock, 'P' for paper and 'S' for scissors
private char chooseHandShape()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    // 0 = Scissors, 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper
    int choice = rand.nextInt(3);

    // player 1 randomized
    char playerChoice = 0;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 0:
        playerChoice = 'S';
        break;
    case 1:
        playerChoice = 'R';
        break;
    case 2:
        playerChoice = 'P';
        break;
    }

    return playerChoice;
}

// Yes/No response
// Returns true if the user enters a 'y' or 'Y'
//
private boolean yesResponse(Scanner scan)
{
    return scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == _YES;
}

// ***********************************************************************
// ***********************************************************************
// ***********************************************************************
// testing code
public void randomTest()
{
    // testing procedure to see if the random choice
    // of a hand shape was essentially even
    int r = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        switch (chooseHandShape())
        {
        case 'R':
            r++;
            break;
        case 'P':
            p++;
            break;
        case 'S':
            s++;
            break;
        default:
            d++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("rock:    " + r);
    System.out.println("paper:   " + p);
    System.out.println("scissor: " + s);
    System.out.println("none:    " + d);

}
```

}

when the `winninghand` method compares it SHOULD return the value 0,1, or 2 based on who won or if theres a tie. I've ran the code and the `chooseHandShape` works fine .

Comment: Its not clear what you want. You're not getting the value returned by winningHand. But please formulate better. Its unclear what you want.

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk I'm trying to get the value that returned by winningHand but I don't know how to go about doing that

Comment: Your code is very messy, same variable is initialized more than once, more than one method doing the same job in addition, your question is ambiguous; whether you want the same values of `p1` and `p2` during entire execution of your program ? kindly be clear in what you want us to help you with.

Comment: @ZainArshad Sorry for the confusion, I'm new to programming & this is my first attempt at creating variuous methods and then calling them. I do want it to be the same for each round, which is why I created the for loop. I was under the impression tht creating the loop would output a different p1 & p2 char each time. I really would appreciate help cleaning up my methods, and understanding how to properly use the int (winningHand) that was returned from the winningHand method. I want to use that integer in my displayRoundResult so that, the method can then add on a point to the players score

Comment: @CorinneBond you have no need to call `winninghand()` in `displayRoundResult()` I mean in single iteration of `For loop` the value of `winninghand` should remain same ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ZainArshad no, you're right.

Comment: @ZainArshad If I properly call the methods in playGame() , my code should run smoothly? But my methods are actually the problem?

Comment: @CorinneBond What is the problem?You said how to call `winningHand()` in `displayRoundResult()` I answered that you don't have to call it at all and you agreed. Now what else is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

All of your `if` statements in `winningHand()` after the first one are incorrectly using `||` when they should be using `&&`.

Also, you're not doing anything with the return value of that method, which is a completely different problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused on HOW to properly use the return value winningHand because I don't think I'm calling the method right in the first place.